# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening everyone I would like to have your help please

in fact i'm trying to return the list of notes in sequences of a quarter the first quarter but I have this error

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row here is my sql code

```
SELECT 
    g1.student_id,
    c.course_name,
    (SELECT 
            g2.marks
        FROM
            grades g2
                JOIN
            courses c1 ON c1.id = g2.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s1 ON s1.id = g2.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s1.id = 1) AS sequences_1_marks,
    (SELECT 
            g3.marks
        FROM
            grades g3
                JOIN
            courses c2 ON c2.id = g3.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s2 ON s2.id = g3.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s2.id = 2) AS sequences_2_marks
FROM
    grades g1
        JOIN
    courses c ON c.id = g1.course_id
        JOIN
    sequences s ON s.id = g1.sequence_id
        JOIN
    exams e ON e.id = s.exam_id
WHERE
    e.id = 1
```

Comment: The error is clear. In queries like `select (select ...)`, the `(select ...)` must return a single value, and it seems that your data has more than one for your query

Comment: yes it is true and I would like to return all the notes of the different sequences how to do to remedy it ???

Comment: yes it is true and I would like to return all the notes of the different sequences how to do to remedy it ???

Comment: If you want that, I recommend you to create a new question (or change this one), and add sample data and expected output. This one asks for the error, and the error is due to that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation function to only receive **one** vaölue

Like `MAX`

```
SELECT 
    g1.student_id,
    c.course_name,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(g2.marks)
        FROM
            grades g2
                JOIN
            courses c1 ON c1.id = g2.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s1 ON s1.id = g2.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s1.id = 1) AS sequences_1_marks,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(g3.marks)
        FROM
            grades g3
                JOIN
            courses c2 ON c2.id = g3.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s2 ON s2.id = g3.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s2.id = 2) AS sequences_2_marks
FROM
    grades g1
        JOIN
    courses c ON c.id = g1.course_id
        JOIN
    sequences s ON s.id = g1.sequence_id
        JOIN
    exams e ON e.id = s.exam_id
WHERE
    e.id = 1
```

OR ADD A `LIMIT 1` with an `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT 
    g1.student_id,
    c.course_name,
    (SELECT 
            g2.marks
        FROM
            grades g2
                JOIN
            courses c1 ON c1.id = g2.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s1 ON s1.id = g2.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s1.id = 1
            ORDER BY g2.marks
        LIMIT 1) AS sequences_1_marks,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(g3.marks)
        FROM
            grades g3
                JOIN
            courses c2 ON c2.id = g3.course_id
                JOIN
            sequences s2 ON s2.id = g3.sequence_id
        WHERE
            s2.id = 2
        ORDER BY g3.marks
        LIMIT 1) AS sequences_2_marks
FROM
    grades g1
        JOIN
    courses c ON c.id = g1.course_id
        JOIN
    sequences s ON s.id = g1.sequence_id
        JOIN
    exams e ON e.id = s.exam_id
WHERE
    e.id = 1
```

Comment: thaks very much